# Область видимости переменных

Tags: переменные, java

Имею несколько методов в одном классе, как мне создать в **одном методе** переменные так, чтобы их можно было использовать и изменять в **другом методе**. Т.е. общая переменная для всех методов.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сделал, спасибо!
нужно в классе, вне какого-либо метода добавить
private static int var = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявите эту переменную как поле класса. Почитать и посмотреть на примеры можно [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 1):

Создайте атрибут класса и используйте его

Comment: мне бы пример